# How can I set a swc theme in Maven?

Tags: apache-flex, maven, pom.xml, flex-mojos

I can't set my custom theme in Maven like I do it in Eclipse by changing theme in project properties.

I note the theme swc in dependencies, the compiler founds it but the theme doesn't change.

Who knows how can I set a custom theme in Maven?

Comment: Which maven plugin do you use? Flexmojos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the scope 'theme' for the dependency of the theme swc. E.g. to use the Spark theme specify this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
  <type>swc</type>
  <scope>theme</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you'll see this compiler option in the output:

```
-compiler.theme /home/cschlipf/.m2/repository/com/adobe/flex/framework/spark/4.1.0.16248/spark-4.1.0.16248.swc
```

Comment: How do you avoid the warnings about theme being an invalid scope?

Comment: I don't. As far as I know this is hardcoded in Maven 3.x and I haven't found a way yet to avoid this warning other than ignoring it in our build management tool.